# AppStoreConnect Subscription Prices not showing up

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase, app-store, app-store-connect

I have 3 IAP already approved in AppStore Connect.

I want to edit one, to add a limited into period.

When I tap on the IAP, the "Subscription Prices" section is indefinitely buffering.

I tried Safari, Chrome, incognito, Windows, Safari on iPhone, everything.
I also checked my Agreements and both Free/Paid apps are Active and the default currency is USD.

I submitted a ticket to Apple, but from experience, they don't really help.

Help?

[image]

Comment: May be a problem with Apple's servers, unless your account has any problems. This usually gets resolved within 24h.

Comment: Unfortunately, it passed more than 24h and still nothing

Comment: the only thing I found in the JS Console is: "TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'tierCountry.fRetailPrice')"

Comment: Please, I am facing the same problem. How Is it solved for you?

Comment: please raise a ticket to apple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue got solved after raising it to apple via a support ticket.

It took them 2 weeks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how much this helps, but I think there's a problem server-side for Apple.

I'm experiencing the same problem and have equally not been able to get any support from Apple around this.

My reasoning here is that 2/3 days ago I couldn't log into my portal as it kept declaring that there was no AppleID attached to that email address. Eventually, as I knew there was, I just left it and hoped it would work itself out. I came back the next day and was able to log into AppStore Connect fine with no issues.

I've seen quite a few comments that Apple have kind of f'ed up their migration over to AppStore Connect, and this fits with the weird login problems I faced. I can definitely replicate your issue and have also reported it to Apple, so I assume that this is one of those things which will magically fix itself in a day or two. (Particularly given user:elbib says it's working for them)

Comment: well... it's been a week now.. and nothing from them

Answer (score 0):

It worked fine for me as of this writing. I’ve used my iPad 8th gen.

Comment: Please consider leaving a comment instead when providing anecdotal support.

Comment: Have you solved it? I am facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

For who that may face this issue.
The title, prices and details that is used to show the product coming from the In-App Purchase have to come from the store. If it comes `null` is because you didn't agreed or assigned the accept from Apple Developer Program and paid apps contract on the App Store Connect. So, do that and try again.
Hope it helps others.

Comment: I'm sorry but this is not the case.

Comment: Hi @AndreiMatei for me in the same case it was the solution and I could explain how it happened. It was just something related to the Apple contracts. But the flagged answer here doesn't make sense... Please, give us more informations.

Comment: well, there is no more info. They didn't give any explanations.